# How to guarantee an exception display on android under ANY circumstances?

Tags: android, exception

I read a lot about using `Toast` or `Log` and putting them into `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(...)`.
But I just can't get ALL exceptions displayed.

Please tell me (or point me to a resource) where it is described how to to it.
With working examples, when possible.

Thank you.

*My guess is: when certain things go wrong (some global exception which destroys the whole app), toasts can't be displayed anymore.*

Comment: Can you tell what exceptions are not getting displayed? (I assume that by "not displayed" you mean that the exception handler is not being called)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just developing don't try to use Toasts to display exceptions just work with Log.e() and the other Log functions it will all get displayed in LogCat you won't loose any exceptions. If you want to notify the UI that an Exception happened do it with a [BroadcastReciever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). So you have the place where you catch the Exception that fires an Intent which contains the message as an extra and in your Activity you just have to

```
 registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("SOME_STRING_IDENTIFYING_THE_INTENT"));
```

Make sure you unregister the Receiver in the Activities onPause method.
The BroadcastReciever has a onReceive method that you can use to fire of the Toast.